# New project using Angular 15 + Firebase 9

Tags: angular, firebase

I've installed node 18.10.0 and I'm trying to create a new Angular 15 project that uses Firebase 9 (hosting, firestore database and authentication) and after the commands shown below the node_modules doesn't have the @angular/fire directory, so the following in app.module.ts import doesn't work

```
import { AngulareFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
Import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

AngularFirestoreModule
```

I really want to stay with Firebase 9, but happy to downgrade Angular. Any ideas on what to do?

```
nvm install 10.10.0

nvm use 18.10.0

npm install -g @angular/cli@15.2

ng new myapp

cd myapp

npm install bootstrap

npm install firebase@9.6.11

npm install -g firebase-tools

firebase init
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

Ng add @angular/fire

Answer (score 0):

I'm digging around to rectify issues I have writing to the Firestore emulators but shouldn't the imports be the following for Firebase 9?

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator  } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getAuth, provideAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getFunctions, provideFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions';


let firebaseApp = provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase));
let firestore = provideFirestore(() => getFirestore());
let auth = provideAuth(() => getAuth());
let functions = provideFunctions(() => getFunctions());
let storage = provideStorage(() => getStorage());
```

or a variation of this, however you want to handle it